# Java 8 filter with method call

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am learning Java 8 lambda and streams and trying some examples. But facing problem with it. here is my code

```
fillUpdate(Person p){
    List<Address> notes = getAddress();
    notes.stream().filter( addr -> addr !=null).map( this::preparePersonInfo,p,addr);
}
private void preparePersonInfo(Person p, Address addr){
    // do some stuff
}
```

Am getting compilation error in .map **addr**(second argument) field.
what wrong in it and could you please provide links to learn java 8 streams.
FYI am following this link [Java 8 lambda](http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/006-how-to-filter-arraylist-stream-java8/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first problem is that `map` method call doesn't declare the `addr` variable.

The second problem is the usage of a method with no return type in `map`.

You can't use a method reference the way to tried (`map( this::preparePersonInfo,p,addr)`), since the parameters for a method reference are passed implicitly. If `preparePersonInfo` only required a single `Address` argument, you could write:

```
notes.stream().filter( addr -> addr !=null).forEach(this::preparePersonInfo);
```

since in this case the `Address` argument would be passed from the Stream.

You probably want to add some terminal operation to the Stream pipeline, or it won't be processed. Since your `preparePersonInfo` doesn't return anything, it can't be used in `map` (as `map` maps the Stream element to something else, so it must return something). Perhaps `forEach` would suit your needs if all you want is to execute an operation on each element of the Stream that passes the filter.

Therefore, the following should work with your current `preparePersonInfo` method:

```
notes.stream().filter( addr -> addr !=null).forEach (addr -> preparePersonInfo(p,addr));
```

Comment: And if the OP really wishes to use a method reference, `filter( addr -> addr !=null)` can be replaced with `filter(`[`Objects::nonNull`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#nonNull-java.lang.Object-)`)`…

Answer (score -1):

Not exactly as asked but filter with method call --with argument-- in Lambda :

```
Stream<MyObject> MyObjectStream = MyObjectList.stream().filter(myobj -> StringUtils.isNotEmpty(myobj.getAccountNumber().trim()));
        MyObjectStream.forEach( o ->
                myService.getAccounts(o.getAccountNumber(), "Test"));
```